# redirect function's stdout on the fly

Tags: python, multithreading

Suppose I have a python function `foo`. I want to run it in the background (using `threading` or `multiprocessing`), and have all its stdout and stderr available in real time as it is produced by `foo`. If `foo` was a shell command, I could achieve this by using `subprocess.Popen` and a generator, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15354403/1113562), **but I need to do this with a python function**. The `multiprocessing` module is good for spawning new processes, but it seems to be hard to get to child's stdout in real time.

P.S: I need this to redirect function's stdout to a webpage as it is generated, using Server Sent Events protocol

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I think this is a bad idea and you should ideally rewrite the `foo` function to return its output in some other way. That said...

If `foo` is just a standard pure-Python function using only standard Python functions to produce its output (`print` and `file.write`), then you could you just redirect its standard output to a `StringIO` or something similar.

Python 2.x example:

```
import sys, StringIO

def foo():
    print "Haha! You can't capture this output!"
    print>>sys.stderr, "... Or this!"

output = StringIO.StringIO()

saved, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, output
sys.stderr = output
foo()
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = saved

print output.getvalue()
```

Comment: "I think this is a bad idea". Well, I'm writing a framework, which is supposed to run user code (function `foo` that is) in a separate process or thread, which may print smth to stdout. I don't know of any better solution, but better design suggestions are wellcome

Comment: To the actual answer, the `foo` should also be ran in the background. I guess it's not trivial to combine these two techniques, or is it?

Comment: @dymtro: Okay, I think I have a better idea of what you're trying to do. Forking into a child process and then capturing its `stdout` is a fairly common pattern in C programs on POSIX-like systems. It's an OS-dependent, low-level operation. You should be able to implement the procedure outlined in this guide, ["Capture the output of a child process in C"](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_the_output_of_a_child_process_in_c.html), in Python rather than in C, by using `os.pipe`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect the output of *only* a function -- you will instead end up redirecting the output of the entire process -- and if that process is threaded then that means every thread's output is now being redirected.

You should check out [generators](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) if you are looking for real-time feedback from a single function.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, my idea was exactly to spawn a new process for this function. But then I don't know how to do that without having that function in a separate script

Comment: @dmytro: In your question you mentioned a new thread as a possibility -- thread's (in Python) are not new processes.  You could use multiprocessing and os.pipe, though.